# Live filter search using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to search data using live filter search using bootstrap filters

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
<div class="row carousel-row lss">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 slide-row">
        <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide slide-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators lsse">
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol> -->
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="uploads/<?php  echo $viewjobregisterid;  ?>/<?php echo $viewjobsid;   ?>/<?php   echo $imagefile5; ?>" alt="Image" style="width: 500px;height: 186px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-content">
            <h4><?php echo $myjobs1["title"]; ?></h4>
            <p><?php  echo $myjobs1["description"]; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-footer">
            <span class="pull-right buttons">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="relocateTo('jobtitle.php?jobtitleid=<?php echo $myjobs1["viewjobsid"]; ?>')">View Job</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script i am using i want to search data for that code.

Answer (score 0):

Complete live search in your page without refreshing

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#search").keyup(function() {

    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $(".data_li").hide();

       $(".data_li").each(function() {

        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

         if(text.indexOf(val) != -1)
         {

             $(this).show(); 

         }

       });

    });

});
```